# NSPredicate filitring issue

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a `PickerView` and `TableView` and I'm loading data from the server to the pickerView, once I select the city in the picker I show the result in the tableView.

To do that I'm using `NSPredicate` to filter it from the Dictionary and show the result... but it doesn't show any value. So please where would be my issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Data called for PickerView

```
{"Status":1,"Response":[{"ID":19,"Title":"G.A","Name":"G.A"},{"ID":8,"Title":"Mexico","Name":"Mexico"},{"ID":17,"Title":"USA","Name":"USA"},...
```

Data called for tableView

```
{"ID":309436,"CountryID":8,"CountryName":"Mexico","Previous":"%3,0","Actual":"%3,0","cast":"%2,9","Event":"M2","Priority":1,"Date":"14.10.2014","Time":"01:50:00"},{"ID":309437,"CountryID":8,"CountryName":"Mexico","Previous":"%2,4","Actual":"%2,5","cast":"%2,4","Event":"M3","Priority":1,"Date":"14.10.2014","Time":"01:50:00"},{"ID":317211,"CountryID":17,"CountryName":"USA","Previous":"%0,1","Actual":"%1,2","cast":"%1,4","Event":"GPS1","Priority":3,"Date":"14.10.2014","Time":"02:00:00"},{"ID":317212,"CountryID":17,"CountryName":"USA","Previous":"%2,4","Actual":"%2,4","cast":"%2,6","Event":"GPS","Priority":3,"Date":"14.10.2014","Time":"02:00:00"},
```

I want to get `Event` and `Date` value.

```
- (void)runURL

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com.ashx"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
 {
     if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
     {
         dicList2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];

         if([[[dicList2 objectForKey:@"Success"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"1"]){

             [dataCalendarArray3 addObjectsFromArray:[dicList2 objectForKey:@"Response"]];
         }
}

- (void)runPredicate
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.CountryName MATCHES ‘%@‘", @"Mexico"];

    NSArray *ar = [dicList2 objectForKey:@"Response"];

    NSArray *filter = [ar filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

    NSLog(@"New List %@",filter);
}
```

Comment: Try this                                                     NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText]; and where you are calling runpredicate?

Comment: @johnykumar it works. Is there a fast way to get the `Event` and `Date` ?

Comment: you can use date formatter for converting in date object after getting string from dictionary.but for getting data from server i think you are doing in right way.

Comment: I get this result
`        Actual = "95,3";
        CountryID = 17;
        CountryName = USA;
        Date = "14.10.2014";
        Event = "***";
        Forecast = "95,8";
        ID = 300183;
        Previous = "96,1";
        Priority = 1;
        Time = "14:30:00";`

Comment: so what you want to do with that?

Comment: I just want to print `Event` and `Date`. But if I can't I will write it in objectForKey format. @johnykumar

Comment: what you are getting in filter array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63036/discussion-between-can-and-johny-kumar).

Comment: @johnykumar can you add your answer please so I can accept the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];